# How to define a lengthy type as a custom type?

Tags: c#, arrays, custom-type

I figure I'm just using the wrong description of what I want and that's why I can't find an answer, but essentially I want to do the following:

```
// Go from this
List<string>[] myvar = new List<string>()[5];
myvar[4].Add("meow");

// To this
LString myvar = new LString();
myvar.Add("meow");
```

I initially tried doing a class `public class LString : List<string>()[]`, but that isn't really valid syntax, so I didn't really know where to go from there.

Comment: You want an array of a list of strings?

Comment: Question about your example: How would your `LString` know you want to add "meow" to the last array of lists, rather than say the first, third, etc.?

Comment: I think he wants to have a preallocated list (of length 5), but he made an array of lists instead?

Comment: Can you explain the context of this logic? This might be a wrong approach...

Comment: I want a fixed size array of lists of strings. I know that I will always have 5, lets say categories. and the number of items in each categories will vary. This will need to be created in a number of places, so I was wondering if there was a way of just making something shorter and simpler that just mapped back to the type that I wanted.

Comment: Will the Categories always be the same?

Comment: The same in that they will always be the same length, they dont mean the same thing

Comment: I think I'll agree with rae1n and say this looks like you'll end up having to jump through hoops no matter what to use this construct.  What's the context for doing this?  Why not have (a) class(es) with the appropriate number of List Properties so you (or your co-workers) know what each List is for?

Comment: I suppose it could be done that way, it just seemed like a wrapper would be easier if it could be done. To represent byte0,1,2 of data that I am getting from a byte array, I would rather use subscripts than myvar.byte0.add

Comment: For a bare array, yeah `myByte[0] = 0` is more sensible than `myByte.byte0 = 0`.  But what you have here is an Array of Lists, so suddenly those positions now likely have some semantic meaning, as you likely only want certain strings to go into certain lists.

Comment: I suppose I should have put this all in the actual question, but im decoding 3 bytes of data, where each byte can have multiple decodes inside it. So I figured, array of three, where you add as many strings as you need per byte. So each index really only represents its byte. It makes more sense and is easier to read when using this, to do so using the syntax I used in the question, I just wanted to simplify the declaration since it's called in many places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an encapsulated method:

```
public class LString
{
    List<string>[] _strListArray;

    public LString(int size)
    {
        _strListArray = new List<string>[size];
    }

    public void Add(int index, string str)
    {
        _strListArray[index].Add(str);
    }

    public void Remove(int index, string str)
    {
        _strListArray[index].Remove(str);
    }

    // insert more code for list manipulation
}
```

This may not be the cleanest code, but it does not inherit from `List<T>`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid something like that, as it would require me to basically make a wrapper function for every function of a List that I end up using versus making a wrapper (class or whatever...the gist of the question) for the structure itself. If this is really the only good way other than just sucking it up and rewriting the type every time, then alright, ill probably just deal with it.

Comment: I agree with you on the recreating all methods needed for list manipulation. This would get rather lengthy depending on what functions you want to have on the array of lists.

Answer (score 2):

To derive a class from `List<string>`, use the following syntax:

```
public class LString : List<string>
{
}
```

It is not possible to further derive the class from an array.  So you'll have to be happy with:

```
LString[] myvar = new LString[5];
```

**Edit:**

Based on feedback, you're better off doing something like this to encompass your list:

```
public class LString
{
  private List<string>[] _lists = new List<string>[5];

  public void Add(int index, string value)
  {
    if (index < 0 || index > 4)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
    _lists[index].Add(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd argue that inheriting from a list is very rarely useful, and quite often problematic. Lists should usually be encapsulated. Not inherited.

Comment: @Marc Might be irrelevant to the question, but I'd love to hear the reasoning.

Comment: @Marc it depends on if your class "is a" list or "has a" list.  It also depends on if you want to be able to simply add additional functionality to the already existing implementation of `List<T>`.

Comment: @Rotem well, firstly List-of-T has no useful virtual methods, so you can't do anything usefully polymorphic (validation etc). Additional methods could perhaps be done better with extension methods. So that means that the main useful other reason to do this would be to add additional fields / properties - but that doesn't work well with some core parts of the framework: standard serializers and data-binding tools assume that something is either (exclusively) a list **or** an entity; thus you cannot properly data-bind or serialize these additional members of your custom list.

Comment: @Matt I've added a longer explanation above - but: very regularly and frequently do I see a question here on SO where someone's code isn't working properly, where the reason is precisely because they inherited from a list rather than encapsulated it.

Comment: There is no functionality being added and it "is a list" not "has a list". This is really just me wanting a wrapper for an array of list of strings.

Comment: I agree with @MarcGravell, to achieve your goal, composition would be preferred over inheritance.